# Double Integral Polar Coordinates

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm supposed to find the area of the region in the first quadrant formed by the following polar equation:

$$r=4\sqrt{2-\sin 2\theta}$$

If I write this as an iterated integral, $\theta$ is going to be between $0$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

I also know that $r$ is between $4$ and $4\sqrt3$ (well, I'm pretty sure).

This gives me the following integral where $I$ is the integrand.

$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_4^{4\sqrt3}I\;dr d\theta$$

As far as the integrand is concerned, since I'm not converting from rectangular do I omit the Jacobian? Also, should the integrand be the function $r$ or just $1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of it this way: call the region whose area you want to compute $D$. Then in rectangular coordinates, the area is given by $\iint\limits_D 1 \, dx \, dy \, dz$. Now convert to polar coordinates, and the integrand becomes $r$ (from the Jacobian).

Also, your bounds on the integral for $r$ should not be 4 to $\sqrt{3}$. They should be $0$ to $4\sqrt{2-\sin(2\theta)}$.

Comment: Okay, I understand the integrand part. However, since $\sin2\theta\in[-1,1]$, doesn't that mean $r\in[4,4\sqrt3]$?

Comment: You may be right, but the bounds on the $r$-integral should not be constant numbers, but rather functions of $\theta$. The only time the $r$-bounds are constant is if your region is the region between two circles.

Comment: Ah I see, thank you so much!